# Advice Regex, check timestamp

Tags: c#, regex, msdn, dngrep

I have a doubt about the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) (Regular Expression) by Microsoft. I have a log file write in this mode.

```
2017-02-20 15:58:45.442 - [XYZ] 155 RADIO_TRAIN_TO_TRACK_INITIATION_COM_SESSION
                                      .VAR1A: 155
                                      .VAR2B
                                      .VAR3z
                                      .VAR4t
    2017-02-20 15:58:46.432 - [XYZ]   32 RADIO_TRACK_TO_TRAIN_CONFIGURATION_DETERMINATION
                                      .VAR1A: 32
                                      .VAR2Y
                                      .VAR3s
                                      .VAR4a
                                      .VAR5w
                                      .VAR6d
    2017-02-20 15:58:48.541 - [XYZ] 156 RADIO_TRAIN_TO_TRACK_INITIATION_COM_SESSION
                                      .VAR1A: 156
                                      .NIDPACKET
                                      .VAR3l
                                      .VAR56
                                      .VAR7b
                                      .VAR100k
```

PROBLEM: I would have an expression to check if FIRST message [XYZ] 155 and SECOND message [XYZ] 32 are consecutive and they are inside a interval of 10 second.

So, MY QUESTION IS: Is [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) enough to resolve this problem? Or i would implement more code (for example to compare the TimeStamp)

Thank you for all! But i have an application in C#, i will try to add your code to modify it.

My idea is:

1) Extract all text to mex [XYZ] 155 and all text to mex [XYZ] 156 (timestamp included)

2) Check if the timestamp are inside the interval of 10 second. Return OK if correct, or return empty solution if not correct.

About first point, i try this regex

```
(?<=\[XYZ] \b155\b(?:(?!\n\d{4}-\d{2}-\d).)*?\n {3,}\.).*(?:\r?\n(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d).*)*|(?<=\[XYZ] \b156\b(?:(?!\n\d{4}-\d{2}-\d).)*?\n {3,}\.).*(?:\r?\n(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d).*)*
```

It extract all text, but not the timestamp. Any suggestion to resolve it?

Comment: You can use `Regex` to extract the timestamp... But then you'll have to compare them, probably converting them to `Timespan`

Comment: @xanatos Thank you, i suspect it. Maybe i believe to implement more code.

Comment: @xanatos, Hi, any suggestion about my edit?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^ *([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}) - (.*)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
var matches = rx.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(x => Tuple.Create(DateTime.Parse(x.Groups[1].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), x.Groups[2].Value)).ToArray();
```

should return an array) of tuples, with `Item1` the `DateTime` of the log and `Item2` the first line of the description. If you want to "save" all the lines of the description it gets a little more complex. From here comparing the `DateTime` of two consecutive items (inside a `for` cycle) is easy.

Variant to extract the *XYZ* (`Item2`) and the number (`Item3`):

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^ *([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}) - \[([^]]*)\] *([0-9]*)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
var matches = rx.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(x => Tuple.Create(DateTime.Parse(x.Groups[1].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), x.Groups[2].Value, x.Groups[3].Value, x.Groups[4].Value)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code like below which doesn't use regex

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication49
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime endTime = DateTime.Parse("2017-02-20 15:58:50");
            DateTime startTime = endTime.AddSeconds(-10);

            Session session = new Session(startTime, endTime);
            session.ReadFile(FILENAME);

        }

    }
    public class Session
    {
        public static List<Session> sessions = new List<Session>();

        public static DateTime startTime { get; set; }
        public static DateTime endTime { get; set; }

        public DateTime time { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<string> properties { get; set; }

        public Session()
        {
        }

        public Session(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
        {
            Session.startTime = startTime;
            Session.endTime = endTime;
        }
        public void ReadFile(string filename)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);

            string inputLine = "";
            Session newSession = null;
            Boolean skip = false;
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if (inputLine.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (inputLine.StartsWith(".") && (skip == false))
                    {
                        newSession.properties.Add(inputLine);
                    }
                    if(!inputLine.StartsWith("."))
                    {
                        string[] array = inputLine.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(array[0] + ' ' + array[1]);
                        if ((time > startTime) && (time < endTime))
                        {
                            skip = false;
                            newSession = new Session();
                            newSession.properties = new List<string>();
                            Session.sessions.Add(newSession);

                            newSession.time = time;
                            newSession.name = array[5];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            skip = true;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```